# L'étymologie de religion

Tags: étymologie

Comme beaucoup de personnes sans doute, j'ai entendu quelques prélats raconter que l'étymologie du mot *religion* était de relier des humains et/ou Dieu (*gion* voulant sans doute dire humains + dieu, me disais-je).

Quelle surprise de lire [le contenu du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/religion) sur ce point : le mot religion ne daterait que de… 1130 ?? Il se rapporterait à des personnes en monastère.

Selon un psautier de… Cambridge (Cambridge était français, à l'époque ?), religion se rapporterait à des personnes en relation avec la divinité, ce qui correspond peu ou prou aux conceptions modernes.

Et ensuite, le mot semble entrer vraiment dans le langage courant, mais seulement 4 siècles plus tard, grâce aux… guerres de *religion*, merci aux protestants.

Wikipédia, [dans un article spécialement consacré au sujet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tymologie_de_religion), donne une version bien différente. Ce mot daterait des romains, et se disputerait entre Cicéron, Saint Augustin et quelques autres, entre des choses qui ressemblent à *relire* et *relier*. L'importance des guerres de religion pour l'usage courant est purement et simplement inexistante pour Wikipédia.

En résumé, il n'y a quasi aucun rapport entre ce que dit Wikipedia et ce que dit le TLFI, mais ce qui me trouble est que j'ai l'impression qu'ils ont tous les deux raison.

Comment comprendre la différence entre les deux approches ? Le mot est-il né à Rome ou à Cambridge ?

Peut-on dire que que le TLF rapporte une histoire concrète des mots, attestée par des sources, tandis que Wikipédia parle plutôt d'histoire de l'idée ? Mais il n'y aurait aucune attestation du mot entre Saint Augustin et le XII<sup>e</sup> siècle ? Et pourquoi le TLF passe-t-il par Cambridge alors ? Peut-on vraiment séparer idée et mot à ce point ?

---

Suite à la réponse de Shlublu (que je remercie)

Ma question porte d'abord sur l'étonnante différence du traitement de l'étymologie, et moins sur cette étymologie. Comme le mot *religion* apparaît caractéristique de l'univers occidental, donc français, il me semble qu'il était intéressant de saisir l'occasion pour essayer de comprendre les pratiques de l'étymologie.

La réponse de Shlublu me confirme dans l'idée que ce mot a eu une histoire pendant l'empire romain, et une histoire depuis le moyen âge. Il me semble donc fautif de ne réserver son étymologie qu'à une histoire de l'un ou de l'autre - mais il resterait à analyser ce qui s'est passé au haut moyen âge.

Il y a d'autres mots que l'on définit souvent par leurs origines gréco latine supposée, comme théâtre, ou philosophie, et considérant qu'ils ont quasi le même sens aujourd'hui... Mais ce sera l'objet d'autres questions, peut être.

Comment: Le lien fourni par Shlublu répond en détail à toutes vos interrogations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Maurice Sachot](http://www.unistra.fr/index.php?id=7962) a publié une étude sur le sujet, [disponible sur le site de l'Université de Lyon 3](http://www.univ-lyon3.fr/servlet/com.univ.collaboratif.utils.LectureFichiergw?ID_FICHIER=1287570601062).

D'après lui, *religion* viendrait de *religio*, au sens de *scrupule*, et qui aurait évolué vers *religion civile*, c'est à dire observance scrupuleuse des rites et pratiques. Ce n'est que par la suite que ce mot aurait évolué vers *vraie religion du vrai Dieu* (*uera religio ueri Dei*), par opposition à *superstitio*, avec les différences d'opinion que l'on peut imaginer quant à ce qui doit être considéré comme *religio* ou comme *superstitio*.

L'auteur met ainsi en évidence le conflit existant entre le rattachement de ce mot à *religare* contre *religere*. Il considère comme biais théologique le rattachement à *religare* (*relier*, *faire lien*), le premier auteur ayant proposé cette étymologie l'ayant justifiée par le lien créé par la piété entre Dieu et les hommes, tout en étant lui-même converti au christianisme. Sachot rattache pour sa part *religio* à *religere* (*recueillir*, *récolter*, *accomplir avec scrupule*), [en s'appuyant sur une démonstration](http://books.google.fr/books?id=TqTfGUZT9dUC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%C3%A9mile%20benveniste%20religere&source=bl&ots=TtU3iUvkoy&sig=WUC47gMO1N3RLC-zILzzkO63kZ0&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=CQrxUce8JcHIhAe-pYGIAw&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%C3%A9mile%20benveniste%20religere&f=false) du linguiste [Emile Benveniste](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Benveniste) et basée sur [l'autorité de la tradition et l'exécution scrupuleuse des rites](http://books.google.fr/books?id=9syR88OrfI0C&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=%C3%A9mile%20benveniste%20religere&source=bl&ots=b0NPYMAuPB&sig=0BETzbw0JuhkBDQ6hwXr5_v82BI&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=CQrxUce8JcHIhAe-pYGIAw&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%C3%A9mile%20benveniste%20religere&f=false.).

Comment: +1 pour le lien sur l'étude

Comment: Oui, super intéressant, mais il m'est difficile de tout dire dans un commentaire, aussi je vais éditer ma question.

Answer (score 7):

Le petit Robert :

> 1085 "monastère" ; latin *religio* "attention scrupuleuse, 
>   vénération",
>
> - de *relegere* "recueillir, rassembler" (de *legere*  "ramasser", et fig. "lire"),
> - ou de *religare* "relier"

Le latin a été la langue universelle du catholicisme romain.
Ces sources véhiculent deux sens originels né de la collation des dits et faits du Christ dont il a fallu d'abord *recueillir* et *rassembler* les témoignages, puis les *relier* entre eux.
Les conciles ont ensuite oblitéré certains témoignages et certaines pratiques pour s'approprier la gouvernance et la maîtrise des fidèles, ce qui a entraîné de nombreuses interprétations du sens des mots, souvent contradictoires.

Comment: Vous faites état d'une date (qui d'ailleurs n'est pas dans le TLFI ? ), 1085, apparition du mot. Puis d'événements se rapportant aux origines du christianisme, largement avant cette date. Je veux bien que le français n'existait pas aux origines du christianisme, mais je m'étonne qu'une idée qui parait si ancienne donne un mot utilisé somme toute assez tardivement, et dont on donne l'étymologie selon deux modes d'explications peu cohérents. Les conciles ne sont pour rien dans les différences TLFI / Wikipédia. (et TLFI / Petit Robert ! )

Comment: @ Istao Les conciles et bulles papales ont donné le droit et la liturgie en adéquation avec leurs temps, laissant chacun interpréter et mettre en place un langage adapté aux circonstances, au différents lieux, aux conflits tant armés que théologiques qui secouait une Europe morcelée. Les relire a postériori et décider quelle est l'interprétation qui devra faire référence donne un point de vue par personne qui investigue. Sans oublier l'influence des croyances grecques qui font de l'idée que vous croyez ancienne ne représentait pas l'univers (mental et langue) des croyants de l'époque.

Answer (score 2):

Dans le dictionnaire Le Littré (malheureusement, l'étymologie n'est pas présente sur http://littre.reverso.net, seulement trouvable dans les applications) :

Prov. religio, religion ; espagn. religion ; ital. religione ; du lat. *religionem*, dont l'étymologie est douteuse entre *relegere*, recueillir, et *religare*, relier. 
Pour **relegere**, on dit que *religare* aurait fait *religatio* (ce qui est inexact, car *re-lig-io* se conçoit, exemple *opt-io*), et on cite la phrase :

> *Religentem esse oportet, religiosum nefas* (voy. FREUND).

en ce sens, *religio* voudrait dire recueil (c'est probablement le sens primitif de lex), recueil de formules religieuses, de pratiques.

 Pour **religare**, on cite la phrase :

> *Falsa religione alligare, alium [deum] pro alio nominando* (d'Aulu-Gelle - II, 28).

Ce serait une formule qui liait les dieux, et l'homme à eux.
 En latin, **religio**, au sens d'état monastique, se trouve dès le Ve siècle.

Comment: Précisions sur *Religentem* en opposition à  *religiosum* : quelle est votre traduction?